# I've TABLOCKed a table. How can I read it?

Tags: sql-server, locking, concurrency, nolock

I've `TABLOCK`ed a table so I can run bulk inserts. How can I read it while it is still locked?

Under normal circumstances, I would call this obviously impossible. Luckily, there is one key factor that makes the circumstances non-normal. In this case, **I don't care at all about ACID**. The only thing that I care about is not cancelling the query that has `TABLOCK`ed the table.

I've tried `WITH (NOLOCK)`, but signs suggest that it does not work. Am I asking for the impossible?

Just to spell it out, suppose that I'm running

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT * FROM [A_Lot_Of_Rows]
```

My goal is to query `Table1` while that runs.

I'm doing bulk inserts and, while they're running, have decided that I want to check some detail. I don't care what row I get said detail from.

Each row in `A_Lot_Of_Rows` has a date in it. `A_Lot_Of_Rows` is truncated by my stored procedure and it is repopulated in date-based batches before being truncated again. By reading an arbitrary row from the table, I can tell what batch I'm on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

### 1. Truncating inside a transaction

This applies if you are truncating the table then loading in batches *within a transaction*.

Truncating a table takes a schema modification (Sch-M) lock, which is the [most restrictive type of lock](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#lock_compatibility). Even reading under the *read uncommitted* isolation level (misleadingly aliased 'nolock') or RCSI requires a schema stability (Sch-S) lock, which is not compatible with Sch-M.

A `TABLOCK` or `TABLOCKX` hint does not normally prevent reading data under *read uncommitted* isolation (but see possibility #2).

Either truncate the table outside the data loading transaction or log your progress separately and query that.

It is unfortunate that truncating a table takes a Sch-M lock, while the equivalent unrestricted `DELETE` does not, but that's how it is implemented.

### 2. The table is clustered

If the table has a clustered index, there is an important difference when using a table lock on the `INSERT` statement (or any of the other ways to specify a table lock on bulk load):

- **With a table lock** and an empty destination, SQL Server can reuse the heap bulk-loading mechanism [`RowsetBulk`](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-empty-clustered), which is essentially an offline index build under the covers. **This takes a Sch-M lock**. No concurrent reads are possible in this case.
- **Without a table lock** and even if the table is not empty, SQL Server can still use bulk load and minimal logging, but it uses the [`FastLoadContext`](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-fast-load-context) mechanism. This takes an exclusive lock ('X') on the target table, but **not Sch-M**. Concurrent reads under *read uncommitted* isolation or RCSI are possible in this case.

The `FastLoadContext` path logs quite a bit more than `RowsetBulk` and can be noticeably slower, but it is still technically minimally logged and more efficient than a fully logged operation. This is all assuming your database and configuration otherwise [qualifies for minimal logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import).

There is another **quirk** to `FastLoadContext` in that the calculations performed by SQL Server to see if minimal logging should be applied do not account for any changes in table cardinality within the current batch (stored procedure in your case).

This means SQL Server may decide not to minimally log because it doesn't notice the table is emptied by the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement in the same procedure. There's no particular workaround for this that I am aware of, aside from performing the truncation in a separate batch.

If you are able to capture actual execution plans for the insert, check if the *Clustered Index Insert* operator has the *DMLRequestSort* property set to true. Cached plan reuse can be a factor here as well, which an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint can help avoid.

Also bear in mind that the first page of data written using `FastLoadContext` is always fully logged. More details in my linked articles inline above.

---

It is also possible to see different blocking behaviour when bulk loading a heap, but that depends on the version of SQL Server you using. See the section headed, "Bulk Load, NOLOCK Queries, and Read Committed Snapshot Isolation" in [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)) (some details do not apply to current versions).

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of table locks.  The DML table lock which is an X lock on the object, like if you added a TABLOCKX table hint, and the excusive schema lock SCH-M, that you get from altering truncating, or partition switching on a table.

READ UNCOMMITTED/NOLOCK will read through a TABLOCKX, but not a SCH-M lock.

Comment: Interesting, but as I recall, my `TABLOCK` hint is not the same as a `TABLOCKX` hint.

Comment: TABLOCK specifies the lock scope.  The lock type is determined by the operation.  So a SELECT with a TABLOCK will be an S lock.  A DELETE with TABLOCK will be an X lock.